# Why is the layout, don't update?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwidget, pychart

I need, to clear my chartViewers from a layout, but when I do, I can't delete the last widget.
when I test the length of my layout, I get 0 but the widget is still here after update of the layout, as in the picture :

[image]

here my code when I delete, the widgets and the graphs

```
print("proceding to delete chart ", chartName, "  at : ", indexGraph)
currentGraph = self.charts[indexGraph]
currentWidget = self.chartVs[indexGraph]

self.chartLayout.removeWidget(currentWidget)
self.chartVs.remove(currentWidget)

currentGraph.clearData()
self.charts.remove(currentGraph)
self.chartLayout.update()

#currentWidget.resetCachedContent()
listGraphs.remove(chartName)
self.refreshListWithOpt(self.chartTree, listGraphs, 1, optGraphs)
```

and here is the code where I create the graphs and add it to the layout:

```
self.charts.append(chartClass(patientStr, exp))

print("\nNew Plot chart ", self.charts[lastIndex].name, " length : ", lastIndex )

listGraphs.append(self.charts[lastIndex].name)
print("list Graphs : ", listGraphs)
self.charts[lastIndex].plotJSON(myData.plot(patientStr, exp))

self.chartVs.append(QChartView(self.charts[lastIndex]))
self.chartVs[lastIndex].setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
self.chartLayout.insertWidget(0, self.chartVs[lastIndex])
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The question is not clear for me.

Comment: Azul agma Ghilas, My problem is with the last widget when I delete it it is still there in my layout, even all what I did until now.

Comment: try with: `currentWidget.deleteLater()`

Comment: @BELLOULGAYA Have You tried `delete currentGraph;` ?

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ, I don't the problem was in the QChartView which was still attached to the parent layout, I get the solution thank you

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, that is perfect, I also find this just before your answer, currentWidget.setParent(None)... But I prefer your solution.

Comment: @BELLOULGAYA If you post the answer, would you mark it correctly?

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah, sure I will do

Comment: Already publish my answer, mark it as correct please. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a widget is added to the main widget the default position is 0, 0, when we add it to a layout this position is handled by it, so if we remove it from the layout it will return to its initial position, visually generating the effect of not being delete, then to solve it we must delete the widget for it we use the method [`deleteLater()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater)

Answer (score 1):

There is the solution, my widget was still attached to layout, even after removeItem. so the solution is `widgetToDelete.deleteLater()`  or `widgetToDelete.setParent(None)`

```
print("proceding to delete chart ", chartName, "  at : ", indexGraph)
currentGraph = self.charts[indexGraph]
currentWidget = self.chartVs[indexGraph]

self.chartLayout.removeItem(currentWidgetItem)
currentWidgetItem.widget().deleteLater()
#currentWidgetItem.widget().setParent(None)

self.chartLayout.removeItem(currentWidgetItem)
self.chartVs.remove(currentWidget)
self.chartLayout.update()

#currentWidget.resetCachedContent()
listGraphs.remove(chartName)
self.refreshListWithOpt(self.chartTree, listGraphs, 1, optGraphs)
```